# How to setup base activity for new Navigation Drawer in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I create `activity` with Android studio, however I don't know how to setup the `fragment class` when the activity is launched. Whenever, I start the `activity` I am getting a blank screen. This means that the home screen is not a `fragment class` screen.

Code is below:

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.


        selectDrawerItem(item);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_dashboard:
                fragmentClass = DashboardFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_importexport:
                fragmentClass = ImportexportFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_backuprestore:
                fragmentClass = BackuprestoreFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_setting:
                fragmentClass = SettingFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = DashboardFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_dashboard, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer

    }

}
```

Comment: In onCreate, you don't have any Fragment loaded

Comment: How can I add ?

Comment: Read the official Android Fragment documentation. It's well answered already. You could call `selectDrawerItem` within the onCreate with whatever Fragment you want to show on start

Comment: i also put selectDrawerItem method in onCreate but not work, please provide me reference.

Comment: If you have updated your code, please update your question. You seem to already know how Fragments work. Here... `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace`

Comment: i solved it. ok

Answer (score 0):

you have already setup fragment classes on click of drawer item.

```
 case R.id.nav_dashboard:
                fragmentClass = DashboardFragment.class;
                break;
```

Here is the code for multiple fragments where you are getting id and opening DashboardFragment.

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_dashboard, fragment).commit();
```

fragments are well replaced over here.

Comment: I also used this in class but it work when I select item. I want to know how to setup base  main class when I start activity

Comment: so you are telling you do not have fragments

Comment: This doesn't answer why the page starts as blank